# Tracking the origin of a SonarQube Scan

Tags: sonarqube

We have a SonarQube server that is actively used by several other teams in the company, but which my team hasn't been using for several years.
When I tried to encourage my team to start monitoring code quality with Sonar again, I discovered that the Project in Sonar is being updated on a regular basis.

However, no-one in the team has any idea where these updates are coming from!

Sonar is not included in our main project POM file (we use Maven), and as far as I can tell, it's not being triggered by Jenkins (the Sonar plugin for Jenkins does not appear to be installed or configured).

That leaves a scheduled execution of a SonarScanner as the most likely source for these updates.  However, in a company with several hundred servers and thousands of users, I have no idea where to start looking for this scheduled job!

Is there anything in the Sonar logs that would point to the source of the update, or anything I can configure so that this kind of information is logged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to monitor to access log of the SonarQube server.
It's in `logs/access.log` of a SonarQube installation.
It includes the IP address and timestamp of requests,
as well as the project key when a scanner pushes analysis results to the server.
It should be easy to identify the origin of any scan.